# What is the tense here, and what is the correct conjugation of "to be"?

Tags: tenses

> I will be mad if Alice states something as though it were true when in fact it was just her opinion.

Is the above sentence in the subjunctive tense? If so, is the second use of "was" correct? Should it be "is"?

I should point out that I am a native English speaker, so this is probably not suitable for ELL stack exchange.

Comment: (*Sigh*) There is no subjunctive tense; there's present and past tenses in English and that's it. "Subjunctive" is what some people call various constructions in English; and what some other people call different constructions. If you're a native speaker, what do **you** think it should be?

Comment: It should be *is*, but many people will use *was* because *were* sounds like past tense, and they're maintaining that parallelism.

Comment: @Barmar if you include that as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: I don't have any documentation from which I can make a good answer. Just personal experience that English speakers tend to be sloppy about tenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s that original sentence with its four verbs highlighted in bold and superscripted with successive ordinals to ease discussion:

1. I **will be**¹ mad if Alice **states**² something as though it **were**³ true when in fact it **was**⁴ just her opinion.

   1. will be
   2. states
   3. were
   4. was

Your sentence has four clauses because it has four verbs.  Clause (2) is
the "if" part of a conditional and clause (1) is the corresponding "then"
part that goes with it.  Clause (3) is an "as if / as though" hypothetical clause.
Clause (4) is a simple statement of fact.

The grammatical concern you have identified here is the tense mismatch
between clauses (2) and (4).
My guess is that the intervening clause (3) with its exotic inflection
distracted the writer enough to make them lose track of the tense from
clause (2) when choosing a matching tense for clause (4).

Careful writers would probably make the tenses of clauses (2) and (4)
match.  So your suggestion to use *is* for clause (4) is the most obvious fix,
and perhaps the most common solution as well:

2. I **will be**¹ mad if Alice **states**² something as though it **were**³ true when in fact it **is**⁴ just her opinion.

   1. will be
   2. **states**
   3. were
   4. **is**

But another solution is to convert the conditional from present to past in
order to distance it and so make it all seem more hypothetical. Once clause
(1) moves from *will be* to *would be*, clauses (2) and (4) should move to
the past tense together:

3. I **would be**¹ mad if Alice **stated**² something as though it **were**³ true when in fact it **was**⁴ just her opinion.

   1. would be
   2. **stated**
   3. were
   4. **was**

## On old subjunctives, and old plurals

Clauses governed by *as if/though* are always remote hypotheticals that
posit a situation contrary to fact:

- In Old English, these always took the past subjunctive not the past
  indicative. But Modern English no longer has an inflectional past
  subjunctive form that can be distinguished from past indicative forms.
- This is just like how Old English also distinguished its verbs’ past
  singulars from their past plurals, but Modern English doesn’t do that
  anymore, either.

So we can no longer see the verb *stated* in clause (2) as hypothetical;
only the past modal in clause (1) signals that this is all a hypothetical scenario.

### Save only for *be* alone

The unique exception to both of those losses in inflectional distinction exists today only in the number-one most common of all verbs in the English language.  It is in *be* alone that we actually **do**
retain a morphological distinction not only between past singular
and past plural but also between past indicative and past subjunctive.
(And even the *were* form that came down to us for past plural looks the
same as the one that came down to us from the past subjunctive.)

That’s why clause (3) takes *as though **it were*** no matter what else is
going on in any other clauses in this sentence. (At least in formal speech and writing, that is. Actual usage by native speakers does **not** invariably choose *as if it were* over *as if it was* here, especially in spontaneous or casual contexts.)

Because of **be**’s unique morphologies, it is sometimes used in
periphrastic formulations of *were to INFINITIVE* as a way of signalling
hypotheticalness in other verbs that would not otherwise be able to show
this in their own inflections.

4. I **would be**¹ mad if Alice **were to state**² something as though it **were**³ true when in fact it **was**⁴ just her opinion.

   1. would be
   2. **were to state**
   3. **were**
   4. was

An alternative to periphrastic *were to INFINITIVE* that also conveys
the hypothetical is to use *should INFINITIVE* under inversion for the "if" part, which need no longer be written because the inversion makes it an "if":

5. **Should**² Alice **state**² something as though it **were**³ true when in fact it **was**⁴ just her opinion, I **would be**¹ mad.

   1. would be
   2. **should state**
   3. **were**
   4. was

But that’s extremely formal. This is all getting pretty long and heavy, so
it isn’t something you’re as apt to hear in spontaneous speech as you might
in the polished prose of formal writing, which affords more time to fiddle
with words.

When you **don’t** have that time, simpler formulations tend to appear. We
can drop clauses (3) and (4) altogether, which makes the analysis a lot
easier, no matter whether this in the present tense:

6. I **will be**¹ mad if Alice **states**² her opinion as fact.

   1. will be
   2. states

Or with backshifting into the past tense to make it more hypothetical:

7. I **would be**¹ mad if Alice **stated**² her opinion as fact.

   1. would be
   2. stated

#### One final note

You may also from time to time encounter the first-person forms *I shall/should* used
for *I will/should* in some speakers and writers, especially those (well-)educated
in southeast England, now mostly older ones or in exquisitely formal contexts.

Comment: Oh my ears and whiskers.